# How to insert text & image together in single column of a table using c#?

Tags: c#, sql, image

I am trying to create a question & answer website.
Here I will save Questions & answers in a database and will retrieve them from database.
The problem is that some question & answer might have images with them. So, how do I insert text as well as images in single column of my database column?

One idea is that I will just upload images on server & will just enter url for that image with the text.
Is there any other simple way to do it ?

Comment: Why does it have to be a single column? Have a separate MEDIA table that would hold images (or whatever other media you want in whatever format you need) and reference it from main Question and Answer tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Referencing the images would be the easiest and best solution. You culd for example save the text using HTML and link to the images from there. Encoding the image binaries into the text would bloat the table and render things like full text search, indexing, etc. useless.

```
// HTML:
<img src="path/to/img.jpg" alt="Alt text">

// Markdown: 
![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)
```